# Is it possible to dynamically add a list or list elements as Spring property?

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I'm scheduling jobs using Spring/Quartz.

My `SchedulerFactoryBean`:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>
            <ref bean="testJob1" />
            <ref bean="testJob2" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="testJob1Trigger" />
            <ref bean="testJob2Trigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The number of jobs i'd like to schedule varies, so i'd like to add them as a list from code.

Basically now i have `testJob1` and `testJob2` jobs.

How can i add `testJob3`, `testJob4` etc. without touching the XML?

Is it possible to define the list of jobs and triggers dynamically?

I mean something like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>
            <ref bean="anArrayListOfJobs" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="anArrayListOfTriggers" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: After the bean was initialized and properties set, it doesn't seem to be possible. You can try to have one job with a list of multiple jobs in it. And you might want to use CopyOnWriteArrayList for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the jobs and triggers dynamically and schedule the job dynamically.

```
    // Create Job
    JobDetailFactoryBean JobDetail = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
    jobDetail.setJobClass(ScheduledJob.class);
    jobDetail.setName("reportJob1");
    jobDetail.setDurability(true);
    jobDetail.setJobDataMap(new JobDataMap());
    jobDetail.afterPropertiesSet();

    // create CRON Trigger
    CronTriggerFactoryBean trigger = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
    trigger.setBeanName("UniqueCronBeanName");
    trigger.setGroup("uniqueCronGroup");
    trigger.setJobDetail(jobDetail.getObject());
    trigger.setCronExpression("0 0 12 * * ?");
    trigger.afterPropertiesSet();
```

Then you can schedule your job by setting it to defined scheduler Factory.

```
    schedulerFactoryBean.getScheduler().scheduleJob(jobDetail.getObject(), trigger.getObject());
```